# add windows Existing User on SQL as sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have Powershell Script to create SQL login on database this script about SQL Login only, i want add windows User on SQL is it possible to add same 
i have change Login type windows but it's couldn't work for me

```
$instanceName = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
$loginName = "ShufflrrAdmin1"
$dbUserName = "ShufflrrAdmin"
$password = "Shufflrr@123"
$databasenames = "Shufflrr", "ShufflrrScheduler"
$roleName = "db_owner"

$server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $instanceName

# drop login if it exists
if ($server.Logins.Contains($loginName ))  
{   
    Write-Host("Deleting the existing login $loginName.")
       $server.Logins[$loginName].Drop() }
$login = New-Object `
-TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login `
-ArgumentList $server, $loginName
$login.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin
$login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
$login.Create($password)
Write-Host("Login $loginName created successfully.")

foreach($databaseToMap in $databasenames)  
{ $database = $server.Databases[$databaseToMap]
    if ($database.Users[$dbUserName])
    {
        Write-Host("Dropping user $dbUserName on $database.")
        $database.Users[$dbUserName].Drop()}

    $dbUser = New-Object `
    -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User `
    -ArgumentList $database, $dbUserName
    $dbUser.Login = $loginName
    $dbUser.Create()
    Write-Host("User $dbUser created successfully.")

    #assign database role for a new user
    $dbrole = $database.Roles[$roleName]
    $dbrole.AddMember($dbUserName)
    $dbrole.Alter()
    Write-Host("User $dbUser successfully added to $roleName role.")
}
```

Comment: Use the domain-qualified login name (e.g. "YourDomain\ShufflrrAdmin1") of the existing Windows user, specify `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::WindowsUser`, and remove the password stuff.

Comment: you got me, i am trying same but it's showing login failed for User !!!

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for details as to the cause of the failed login. A login attempt with Windows authentication will fail if the app includes userid and password in the connection string instead of indicating Windows authentication (e.g. `Integrated Security=SSPI`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using an additional PowerShell module, this becomes infinitely easier. I'm also going to assume that you're *not* adding the Login to the server `sysadmin` role but instead want to add it to the `db_owner` *database* role, as that's what your existing code is doing.

Grab [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/install/) and import it into your PowerShell session.

```
$instanceName = ".\SQLEXPRESS";
$databasenames = "Shufflrr", "ShufflrrScheduler";
$roleName = "db_owner";
New-DbaLogin -SqlInstance $instanceName -Login YOURDOMAIN\YOURUser -Force;
# -Force will drop & recreate the login for you. Both SqlInstance and Login take collections, so you can pass multiple instances and multiple Windows accounts and they'll all be taken care of without you writing a loop

Add-DbaDbRoleMember -SqlInstance $instanceName -Database $databasenames -Role $roleName;
# All parameters here take collections of objects, so you don't have to loop over them yourself.
```

If you *do* want to add the Login to the `sysadmin` server role, check out `Add-DbaServerRoleMember`.

You can create & manage SQL logins with these functions as well, just check out the documentation and examples in `Get-Help New-DbaLogin -Full`

Comment: Hi alroc, actually,  this command New-DbaLogin not exist on my PS module even i am not able to update, that's why i am using above script , can we replace SQLlogin as windows                                                                                   $login.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin

Comment: @Biren that's correct, that function will not work until you install and import the `dbatools` module as I noted in the first paragraph (and if you're managing SQL Server, you _really_ want to be using this module). You can install it to just your user scope without elevated permissions via `install-module -scope currentuser dbatools`